# Encode between Objective-C and swift, does not match

Tags: objective-c, swift, encode

My application's network request is encoded.

In Objective-C

```
NSData *encodeData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dataStr = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

I want to transform it to swift.
Here is the swift code:

```
let dataEncodeTemp = dataTempStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let dataStr = dataEncodeTemp?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

I think , the result should be the same. But it does not.

The Objective-C data:

```
(lldb) po str// initial
{"userType":2,"password":"qazwsx2","account":"15921810000"}

(lldb) po dataStr // encoded
eyJ1c2VyVHlwZSI6MiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJxYXp3c3gyIiwiYWNjb3VudCI6IjE1OTIxODE3MDUzIn0=
```

The swift data:

```
po dataTempStr // initial
"{\"userType\":2,\"account\":\"15921810000\",\"password\":\"qazwsx2\"}"

(lldb) po dataStr

▿ Optional<String> // encoded
  - some : "eyJ1c2VyVHlwZSI6MiwiYWNjb3VudCI6IjE1OTIxODE3MDUzIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJxYXp3c3gyIn0="
```

I want to know why , and solve it.

I shall try the bridge.

Any good solution?

Comment: That are two different strings (key-value pairs in different order). Why should the Base64 encoded strings be equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't ever going to match, seeing as the two strings have JSON keys in differing orders; one is `userType`, `password`, `account`; the other is `userType`, `account`, `password`.